# WordPress:горизонтальная прокрутка DIV

Tags: css, wordpress, прокрутка, html, slider

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какой-то плагин или простой способ без встраивания JS библиотек а-ля wow.js и различных слайдеров осуществить горизонтальный скролл  блоков, по нажатию на стрелку влево/вправо. Особое спасибо за примеры кода ;-) 
JS главное без подключения библиотек. Максимум JQuery.

[image: Пример]

Comment: "По нажатию" работает только js. Вопрос можно закрывать.

Comment: @KAGGDesign ok, упростил вопрос. JS используем, но без библиотек. Максимум JQuery